# Smarty php .tpl - Calling a Function

Tags: php, joomla, smarty

I have some smarty php code:

in my sample.tpl file:

```
{require_once(test.php)}
{php}
echo test();
{/php}
```

and in my test.php file:

```
<?php
function test(){
  return "hi";
}
?>
```

For some reason, this breaks the entire template and does not work. Also note that `{php} echo "hi" {/php}` works fine.

Ultimately, I just need to run code attached to a button. If there's an easy way to do this in smarty (eg. an if statement or something), let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't need to use `require` or `require_once` inside Smarty, a function available in the scope of the caller script (which loaded the template) should be available in the template too...

Comment: I'm trying to include it in the template itself. I noticed that I cannot define functions inside the {php} {/php} tags. Is there a workaround for that? I just need a simple button to execute a few lines of code.

Comment: If you need a button inside HTML to execute some action, you probably need to use Javascript, or if you really need to request the server (PHP), you use Ajax, a PHP function is generally used to organize your PHP code.

Comment: All of my classes (db models etc) are in php. The issue is that in the smarty tpl file, I can't write the php code I need to to handle the form submit. I need to know how to declare functions in smarty.

Comment: Ok but, handling form submit is considered as "logic code" and thus it should not be put into a Smarty template. As I said if you really need to call a custom PHP function you define it in the calling script and use it inside your Smarty template.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `require_once()` in Smarty.
You probably need to move it to your PHP block:

```
{php}
require_once("test.php");
echo test();
{/php}
```

Alternatively, if you're using Smarty V3, use of functions and `{php}` blocks may be restricted by security settings: https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.security.tpl

Comment: No, I'm on v2. It blocks me from even doing `{php}
function test() {return "hi"}
echo test();
{/php}` I need to find a way to define a function there and then use it.

Comment: @JayShri That doesn't work because you're missing a `;` after your `return` statement.